# Deletion of multiple items(Including last item) from recyclerview list It throws error IndexOutOfBound

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, recyclerlistview

Below code to select multiple items from the Recyclerview list.

```
        holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {

              //  if (selectedPosition == position) {
                 //   selectedPosition = -1
//                    notifyItemChanged(position);
               // }
                selectedPosition = position;
                isSelect = true
                notifyItemChanged(position);
                items.get(position).id?.let { it1 -> deletList.add(it1) 
}
```

performing delet action on the list on selected item position.

```
    fun removeSelectedItems(){
    mSelectedItems.sortedDescending()
    mSelectedItems.forEach{ itemIndex ->
        items.removeAt(itemIndex)
        notifyItemRemoved(itemIndex)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
    mSelectedItems.clear()
}
```

}

On ButtonClick deleting the selected items from recycler view list

```
deletebutton.setOnClickListener {
                   
                    removeSelectedItems()
                    selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION

                }
```

**Deleting multiple item including last item in any order until last item is selected it is throwing error index out of bound because if any item above last item get deleted list size decreases and index still remains at position? help is appreciated.**

```
var deletList: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
var items: ArrayList<GetListModel>
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): OutagesViewHolder {
        return OutagesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent!!.context).inflate(
                R.layout.chats_list_item,
                parent,
                false
            )
        )
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: OutagesViewHolder, position: Int) {


        val o: Any = items.get(position)


    holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
    
                    if (selectedPosition == position) {
                        selectedPosition = -1
    //                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                    }
                    selectedPosition = position;
                    isSelect = true
                    notifyItemChanged(position);
mSelectedItems.add(selectedPosition)
                        items.get(position).id?.let { it1 -> deletList.add(it1)}
    
}

deletebutton.setOnClickListener {
               
                removeSelectedItems()
                selectedPosition = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
                holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#00000000"));

            }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you're deleting multiple you've to loop it... selectedPosition hold newly selected index only right

Comment: @GobuCSG It always hold newly selected. can you help me with code snippet. like what should i do likw how should i put this in loop?

Comment: Can you confirm After long press user will choose items then need to delete with another action button right?

Comment: @GobuCSG yes after clicking on another button delete action is happening.

Comment: I added output as well.

Comment: Can you update your question? and Add your error log and update your changes

Comment: What is this? if (selectedPosition == position) {
                    selectedPosition = -1
//                    notifyItemChanged(position);
                }

Comment: Is it uncheck again?

Comment: @GobuCSG i have commented it out

Comment: Follow the below steps... You doing something wrong... You can see output as well

Comment: @GobuCSG i followed below steps still getting same error.
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 2, Size: 2
        at java.util.ArrayList.remove(ArrayList.java:503)
        at com.chatappninjaz.adapters.ListAdapter.removeSelectedItemsList

Comment: @GobuCSG i Am getting list from model class.
var items: ArrayList<GetListModel>

Comment: data class not an issue.

Comment: Below I attached screenshot as well. If you can't fix share whole adapter class...

Comment: this one  selectedPosition = position;
items.get(position).id?.let { it1 -> deletList.add(it1)}

What is the usage?

Comment: @GobuCSG Its working fine now.
i was doing one mistake i just have to decrement the position.

Comment: Nice to hear... After long time you resolved....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

**Output**

[image]

We can achieve multiple way

**Declare a list in your adapter**

```
private var mSelectedItems = arrayListOf<Int>()
```

**On your view holder chosen index add to the list**

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(View.OnLongClickListener {
// Selected item index
mSelectedItems.add(layoutPosition)
}
```

**Your delete function like this**

//Single or multiple call this same function

```
fun removeSelectedItems(){
mSelectedItems.sortedDescending()
    mSelectedItems.forEach{itemIndex ->
        YOUR_ITEM_LIST.removeAt(itemIndex)
        notifyItemRemoved(itemIndex)
    }
    mSelectedItems.clear()
}
```

OR

```
fun removeSelectedItems(){
    YOUR_ITEM_LIST.removeAll(mSelectedItems)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
    mSelectedItems.clear()
}
```

OR

If you've bulk record go with **Diffutil**...

Here is the example
https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/ListAdapter

You can use normal recyclerView adapter as well.

Comment: When i select 3 or more items it is giving IndexOutOfBoundsException. if i select list from start or top it gives error but when i select list from bottom it is removing the item without any errors.

Comment: Which adapter you're using!? Can you add your adapter class here... It won't throw out of bound exception...

Comment: I am using recyclerView.adapter . Main issue is when i am selecting 0 or last index my app is crashing at YOUR_ITEM_LIST.removeAt(index) as it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException .
OnItemlong click adding to list -> clicking delete button ->  removing items between 1st and last. and if we particularly select last it will delete that but not 1st item.

Comment: Add your adapter class here.

Comment: I have edited it and added my adapter code above. IndexOutOfBoundsException is because item is removed and list size decreases and my selected item is at last index.

Comment: What is the usage selectedPosition? Why you're managing another delete list!? You've position inside bindViewHolder and this answer is enough to handle delete

Comment: app is crashing because  removing the last item in your data set (e.g. position 10) and then telling the adapter that the item at position 10 has changed... but now the maximum position in your data set is 9.
Well only one list is enough. this anser is handling delete but the issue is size of list changes and app crashes.

Comment: notifyItem won't impact. Notify will remove the view. You're doing something wrong. First remove unwanted codes in your adapter. If you've debug skill you can fix. Can you add your error log  here.

Comment: Sort **mSelectedItems** in decending order before using forEach. For example the list has 8 items, 3rd, 5th, 7th item are selected for delete. If deleting in accending order, after 3rd is deleted correctly, the 5th item of the original list is now the 4th item of the updated list. So still calling delete on 5th position is wrong and will result in OutOfBounds when delete 7th item (because now only 6 items in the list) . However if deleting in decending order, delete 7th, 5th and then 3rd item can avoid such problems.

Comment: @i_A_mok Good catch... Thanks for remaining

Comment: @PrateekSharma I updated my answer. Follow either one.

Comment: @GobuCSG
i tried using sortedDescending(). Still getting same error.
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 5, Size: 5

For removeAll(mSelectedItems)
Type inference failed. The value of the type parameter T should be mentioned in input types (argument types, receiver type or expected type). Try to specify it explicitly.
so i am confused how to use removeAll()

Comment: Pass the items instead of index values. Modify the mSelectedItems type

Comment: @i_A_mok tried using decending order but it still takes the index in increasing order

Comment: Can you update your question...

Comment: @GobuCSG i have updated the question and code as well. all items are getting removed but still after selecting multiple items (with last item) it throws index out of bound error

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem and had to solve it in a very specific way. The way i deleted the items was from within the adapter itself.

1. First which is the most important is to store an instance of the recyler view within the adapter itself.
2. Second you store the postions of your selected recyclerView items in an array list using holder.getAdapterPosition()
3. Third you iterate through this list in a for loop and using the recycler view instance you created in the first step get the view holder for every position using recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition()

One thing you need to note is you need to sort the list in step 2 in ascending order first and also the position you feed into the parameter for the 3rd step has to be reducued by the varaible you use for the for loop as the position in the adapter keeps changing.

Here I have provided my sample code I used the viewHolder to call a certain animation I wanted to call on delete its not necessary to use the viewHolder.

```
public class Your_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Your_Adapter.ViewHolder>{
   private final RecyclerView recyclerView;
   private ArrayList<Integer> selected_Items_position = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

   holder.container.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     selected_Items_position.add(holder.getAdapterPosition());
     
     // If you want to unselect the item you will have to implement your 
     // own logic also ull have to use something like selected_Items_position.remove(Integer.valueOf(holder.getAdapterPosition())); to remove the item from the selected list
   }
}

public void removeSelectedItems() {

   ViewHolder holder;
   Collections.sort(selected_Items_position);

   for (int i = 0; i< selected_Items_position.size(); i++) {

     holder = (ViewHolder) recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(selected_Items_position.get(i)-i);
     int actual_position = holder.getAdapterPosition();

     // Alternatively you could directly use 
    //int actual_position = selected_Items_position.get(i) - i;

    your_list_for_adpater.remove(actual_position);
    holder.item.startAnimation(remove); // Call animation on remove
    notifyItemRemoved(actual_position);
    }
   selected_BinItems_position.clear(); // dont forget this or ull get index out of bounds

}  
    
}
```